# How to partially replace subarray

Tags: php

```
function doSomething($config = null) {
    $default = [
        'name' => 'Chan',
        'age' => 36
    ];

    if ($config !== null) {
        $default = array_merge($default, $config);
    }

    var_dump($default);
}

doSomething(); // This one get name is chan and age is 36
doSomething(['age' => 10]); // This one get name is chan and age is 10
```

I want to have a default config data, and if I pass some parameter to function use array_merge to do partially update, but it won't work with subarray.

```
function doSomething($config = null) {
    $default = [
        'name' => 'Chan',
        'age' => 36,
        'sub' => [
            'a' => 1,
            'b' => 2
        ]
    ];

    if ($config !== null) {
        $default = array_merge($default, $config);
    }

    var_dump($default);
}

doSomething(); // This one sub is ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2]
doSomething(['sub' => ['a' => 3]]); // This one sub is ['a' => 3]
```

How to replace the config partially on subarray?

Comment: What do you mean with `but it won't work with subarray`? Your code return  `sub = ['a' => 3]` with `b` removed, do you want to keep the `b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [***array_replace_recursive***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php) function:

```
function doSomething($config = []) {
    $default = [
        'name' => 'Chan',
        'age' => 36,
        'sub' => [ 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2 ]
    ];

    if (!empty($config)) {
        $default = array_replace_recursive($default, $config);
    }
    print_r($default);
}

//doSomething(); // This one sub is ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2]
doSomething(['sub' => ['a' => 3]]);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Chan
    [age] => 36
    [sub] => Array
        (
            [a] => 3
            [b] => 2
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive to replace default config:

```
<?php
function updater( $old, $new ) {
    if ( is_array(current($old)) && is_array(current($new)) ) {
        return updater($old, $new);
    } else {
        return array_merge($old, $new);
    }
}

function doSomething($config = null) {
    $default = [
        'name' => 'Chan',
        'age' => 36,
        'sub' => [
            'a' => 1,
            'b' => 2
        ]
    ];

    if ($config !== null) {
        foreach( $config as $key => $value ) {
            $default[$key] = updater($default[$key], $value);
        }
    }

    print_r($default);
}

doSomething();
doSomething(['sub' => ['a' => 3]]);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Chan
    [age] => 36
    [sub] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 2
        )

)
Array
(
    [name] => Chan
    [age] => 36
    [sub] => Array
        (
            [a] => 3
            [b] => 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$default_data = [
        "name" => "Meraj",
        "age" => 21,
        "education" => [
            "school" => "JMI",
            "college" => "GGSIPU"
        ]
    ];
    function modifyArrayData($default_data, $new_data = null)
    {
        foreach ($new_data as $key => $value) {
            if (!is_array($value)) {
                $default_data[$key] = $value;
            } else {
                $default_data[$key] =modifyArrayData($default_data[$key], $value);
            }
        }
        return $default_data;
    }

    $new_data = ["name" => "Coder", "education" => ["school" => "Jamia"]];
    $test = modifyArrayData($default_data, $new_data);
    var_dump($test);
```

As the data we need to modify can be  a multidimensional array of unknown depth hence we need to use recursion and handle respectively.